# death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received

Tags: linux-kernel, systemd, vpn, ipsec

I have problem with my Linux when I try to shut it down.

```
init 0
```

I get the following error:

```
death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received
setsockopt recvref[30]: Protocol not available
```

The sytem will be blocked. Sometimes it shuts down after a while, sometimes not.

How can I solve this problem? The system should be efficient in that way.

Should I modify something in `systemd`?

Comment: Which distribution and distribution version are you on? (For example, Fedora 19, Debian 7.1, ...)

Comment: Are you using a VPN? More specifically, are you using an "L2TP IPSEC" client to facilitate a VPN?  There are other complaints regarding this, `death_handler` is likely part of a **[POE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Object_Environment)** module used in the L2TP client (or client interface).

Comment: Yes your issue sounds similar to this one: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Ticket/Attachment/445928/218846. Is there more information around that error message?

Comment: yes i am using VPN module inside the system. So This is related to this module not to the system ?

Comment: When i start the system again, i get  this error:
    setsockopt recvref[30]: Protocol not available